# How can I pass a value to animation event?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a script that can determine which button is selected after the animation event occur.

[Image of the category selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1spZB.png)
[This is the collision code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooqx5.png)

After selecting a category button, the main camera will be redirected to this category coordinates.
Is there a way to pass a value after I click on the button?

*Example:*
If I click on animal, I want to pass the value **animal** on the category scene script.
Is it possible?

Hope someone can answer my question.

Comment: Most probably your question was down-voted because of poor formatting and posting your code as a picture. If you want other users to be able to test/edit/debug your code, don't post it as a picture since people won't bother typing it from scratch : posted as a text you simply have to copy-paste it. Hope this comment will help you for future questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a static value that will be the selected category :

```
public static string selectedCategory;
```

And when one of the category is selected you simply give it the value of the category, so for animal it would be :

```
selectedCategory = "animal";
```

Because the value selectedCategory is static you can access it from any script.

Comment: thanks for the immediate reply sir. ill try it. ill let you know after.. tnx

Comment: Thank you so much sir. been solving this for days. hahaha.. i just call the scriptname.static variable and set the value. then it works.. thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure I'm happy it helped :)